# UITextField in input dialog not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am implementing a simple dialog which asks for a name. This is my code:

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
[dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
[dialog setMessage:@" "];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
[nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[dialog addSubview:nameField];
CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 20.0);
[dialog setTransform: moveUp];
[dialog show];
[dialog release];
[nameField release];
```

It used to work fine but in iOS 7 the textfield doesn't show up. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will not work anymore in iOS7
try this instead

```
  UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:NSLocalizedString(@"Enter a phone number",nil)  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",nil), nil];
                alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
                [alert setTag:1];
                [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
                [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
                [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"Enter Number here", nil)];
                [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
                [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];

                [alert show];
                [alert release];
```

You can change your keyboard type for your requirement.

Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this...And there is no need to add text field as subview.

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
                [dialog setDelegate:self];
                [dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
                [dialog setMessage:@" "];
                [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
                [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

                dialog.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 20.0);
                [dialog setTransform: moveUp];
                [dialog show];
[dialog release];
[nameField release];
```